# Is the sigspec for 0 EXIT or SIGEXIT or exit?

Tags: linux, shell, signals, exit, trap

I need to write a trap which tracks when a process exits (amongst other things) and removes a temporary file. I'd prefer to use the sigspec instead of number for better code readability, the relevant snippet is

`trap 'rm "$temp"' 0 SIGHUP SIGTERM`

Should the sigspec for `0` be `exit`, `EXIT` or `SIGEXIT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shell Command Language, trap](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) on POSIX specification reads

> The condition can be EXIT, 0 (equivalent to EXIT), or a signal specified using a symbolic name, without the SIG prefix, as listed in the tables of signal names in the [<signal.h>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) header defined in XBD Headers; for example, HUP, INT, QUIT, TERM. Implementations may permit names with the SIG prefix or ignore case in signal names as an extension. Setting a trap for SIGKILL or SIGSTOP produces undefined results.

[Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) permits singals to be prefixed by SIG,

> Signal names are case insensitive and the SIG prefix is optional.
> If  a  sigspec  is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the shell.

but since EXIT is no signal (see `man 7 signal` or [<signal.h>](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)) you cannot use SIGEXIT not even with Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Just try it. Bash will tell you:

```
paul $ trap 'echo Foop' EXIT
paul $ trap 'echo Foop' SIGEXIT
bash: trap: SIGEXIT: invalid signal specification
paul $
```

The 'real' signal names can be either with or without the SIG... part. But signal zero does not really exist (and has no name): `kill -0` checks the PID exists but does not send any signal. Bash takes the trap action but there is no actual signal -- it just knows it has stopped processing the script.

Comment: I actually tried doing this before asking here. You're correct `bash` throws out an `invalid signal specification` for `SIGEXIT`. Had recently switched to Zsh, and was inadvertently testing on Zsh (which allows both `SIGEXIT` and `EXIT`), but the script is targeting `env sh`. Hence, the confusion. Thanks though, I'll stick with `EXIT` as it seems to work on both `bash` and `Zsh`.

Comment: @computronium if you’re targeting `sh` you should test with a less featureful POSIX shell, not just Bash and Zsh (*e.g.* `dash` which is the default `sh` on Debian and derivatives).